# Linker error when declaring a function just before calling it

Tags: c++, xcode, linker, clang, undefined-symbol

I've got an update function in my game that contains the following code:

```
void DrawMiniFPSCounter();
DrawMiniFPSCounter();
```

The `DrawMiniFPSCounter()` function is declared in a file called miniFPSCounter.cpp, which is part of the build target (I'm using Xcode). When building, I get a linker error saying that the `DrawMiniFPSCounter` symbol cannot be found. I've tried removing the declaration above and just calling `DrawMiniFPSCounter()` but that results in a 'symbol not found' error during compilation. Why would the linker have trouble finding this symbol? Is it something to do with the order in which symbols are resolved in the project?

EDIT: I ran the command `nm hrMiniFPSCounter.o | grep Draw` in my build directory, and got the following output:

```
00000000 T __Z15DrawMiniCounteriiiii
0002d040 S __Z15DrawMiniCounteriiiii.eh
00000a00 T __Z18DrawMiniFPSCounterv
0002d148 S __Z18DrawMiniFPSCounterv.eh
00000560 t __ZL9DrawDigitiiib
0002d128 s __ZL9DrawDigitiiib.eh
```

is this normal? Why the extra characters on the end of the function names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience most common "errors":

1. Was the file (really) compiled?
2. Was it (really) linked correctly?
3. Did you give the function the name you thought you did?
4. *new* Namespace issues :)

Are you sure that the miniFPSCounter.cpp file is compiled (/have been incouded in the project in the right way)? I guess what you are experiencing could be caused by a few different things,but in lack of more information I would say: Try to make sure that the cpp file is being compiled (maybe introduce a few syntax errors which would give rise to a compilation error if it is indeed compiled) and when you are sure about that, you can start checking for other stuff (suchas  that it is being linked correctly, etc)

Edit: Putting checklist on top.

Comment: I added `#error Compiling mini fps counter` to the beginning of hrMiniFPSCounter.cpp and it triggered that error, so I'm guessing that means it's getting compiled. How do I check if it's being linked correctly? I can see that the file is in the 'Compile sources' phase of the target if that helps.

Comment: Hmm I think that _theoretically_ it does not have to mean that it is being compiled, since there is (usually) a preprocess phase that resolves pragmas and macros etc in preparation for compilation. But sure, practically it probably is being compiled as you mentioned. I would still try with a few syntax errors tho and then remedy those syntax errors and let it compile just to know that a fresh object file is being created. (clean build is never wrong in these circumstances).

Comment: As for seeing if it links correctly. Hmm. I would check if it is included in the "link phase" specification, if there is one (a bit rusty on XCode) and also try to list the symbols from the object file. Maybe the function symbol is named in an unexpected way (for instance due to some C++ name mangling issue). I'm a bit uncertain as to exactly how to list the symbols in XCode, but _nm_ seems a good choice. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nm.1.html

Comment: I've given it another go, added a line saying `float int;` near the top of the file and a syntax error was given. I then cleaned and built again, and I'm still getting the missing symbol error. I then went to the folder with the `.o` files and ran `nm hrMiniFPSCounter.o | grep Draw`. I'll edit my original question to show the output (it won't format well in a comment).

Comment: Do you have the function in a namespace?

Comment: Bingo! That was it. The function wasn't declared within a namespace but its declaration (on the line before it is called) was within a namespace. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The extra characters are (_probably_) from the function signature, i.e. it's parameters. 4 "i"s would be a 4 int parameter function. And the v would signify a void function. (guessing a bit here, unless it's mentioned in the c++ standard or they conform to some standardized object file symbol format it would be up to the compiler/linker pair to do what they want with the symbols I guess). In light of your problem though, I'm not quite sure what the next step would be. Maybe you can compare the symbol name of a function that it does not complain about to the one it complains about.